zoom fit all visible markers in google my maps
Let's say you are planning a cross-country trip. There may be many place markers in your Google My Maps file. Is there a way to zoom fit all the (visible) place markers so that we can see them all at once? As opposed to manually zooming and panning? There must be a Google Maps javascript API that can help in this task.

You could [edit] this question to be more focused on a software recommendation and then we could migrate it to [softwarerecs.se]. Right now it is somewhere between [softwarerecs.se] and [so]

edited to fit here
